# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - NodeJS : Get certificate SSL from Letsencrypt without Beanstalk Load Balancer

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt

For my nodejs application in Elastic BeanStalk, without Beanstalk Load Balancer I want to set up a Letsencrypt certificate and keep the classic domain provided by AWS : xxx.xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com

After several searches I found two possible solutions :

1 - Using an .ebextensions file => to install Certbot, get a Letsencrypt certificate and config Nginx.

great post about that => https://bluefletch.com/blog/domain-agnostic-letsencrypt-ssl-config-for-elastic-beanstalk-single-instances/

2 - From an ssh connection, install Certbot, generate a certificate and Upload it to IAM AWS.

Docs AWS : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-ssl-upload.html

For both solutions I have the same error message during domain verification by Certbot.

I think that the directory generated by certbot for the verification isn't accessible..

Error :

> ```
> To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
> entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
> contain(s) the right IP address.
> ```

So, my question is : What's the best way to setup a SSL Certificate to get the green lock for a Node Js Elastic BeanStalk application without Beanstalk Load Balancer ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to get a certificate for `elasticbeanstalk.com`? You can only obtain certificates for domains that you own, and I'm pretty sure Amazon owns that domain. If you register your own domain and then get a certificate, you should be able to install it onto your instance.

Comment: @Brian Actually, I don't have a domain name and in this case i can't use AWS Certificate Manager. I use this application as webhook to communicate with the Facebook API. that's why I need an encrypted connection. Thank you for your answer. I finally find the solution. I created a git for that https://github.com/SammyHam/LetsEncrypt-SSL-config-for-Elastic-Beanstalk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the solution :

I took inspiration from this [script](https://gist.github.com/tony-gutierrez/198988c34e020af0192bab543d35a62a) and created one using WEBROOT MODE.

I created a git to share this solution :

https://github.com/SammyHam/LetsEncrypt-SSL-config-for-Elastic-Beanstalk

Comment: Thanks for this @Sam, I tried your github code on an AWS Linux 2 Elastic Beanstalk setup but I get 502 Bad Gateway. My logs show the following

`connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 132.123.234.43, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3030/", host: "mydomain.uk"`

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**
Generate a SSL certificate (you can use a free one at https://www.sslforfree.com/), download paste the public(certificate.crt) and private key(private.key) in `./ebsextensions/certs.config` and deploy to elastic beanstalk

Step by step tutorial on how to enable https on single instance elastic beanstalk environment,
with http to https redirection.
This tutorial uses Node.js as platform, but it includes instructions for other platforms too.

[elastic-beanstalk-&-nginx-conf](https://%20https://github.com/avoup/Elastic-beastalk-single-instance-https)

[Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTXS3a67-9c)

[AWS - EB - configuration docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html)

**Troubleshooting**

- Make sure port 443 is listed in the security group.